# How can I combine Getx and go_router in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx, flutter-go-router

I use Getx in my flutter app and want to add go router for deep link configuration.
this is a part of code:

```
 return GetMaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: 'App_Name',
              theme: theme,
              initialRoute: '/',
              onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoute,
              ...
```

I want to change top code same this:

```
 return GetMaterialApp.rouer(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'App_Name',
          theme: theme,
          routerConfig: _router,
          onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoute,
          ...
```

but after adding .router this command the below line can not recognize:

> onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoute,

how can I combine these two part?

Answer (score 2):

```dart
return GetMaterialApp.router(
    routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
    routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
    routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
    ...
);
```

`_router` is GoRouter instance

Here is the link
https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2778#issuecomment-1659779574